# Cauchy integral theorem: Is analyticity enough? Do we need a simply connected domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that if $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain, containing a closed contour $\gamma$, then by the deformation of the closed contours to a point, it's simple to show that

$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$

But what if we don't know information about the domain? **Does the above statement still hold if $f$ is analytic *just* on the loop $\gamma$?** Let's assume we have no information about the rest of the domain. I think it still holds, but this is an intrinsically stronger statement than Cauchy's, which makes me worry :). I can't think of a counterexample, though.

Analyticity $\implies$ differentiability$\implies$ the existence of an anti-derivative, right? Then,

$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = F(z_{0})-F(z_{0})=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Consider the integral
$$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z},$$
where $\gamma$ is the unit circle, traversed once anticlockwise.

In particular, what is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z}$ on any domain (1) containing $\gamma$ and (2) on which it is analytic?

Comment: Cool, $1/z$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\}$, but it wouldn't have a clear anti-derivative where $Log z$ crosses its branch cut. And in order to evalutate $\gamma$ using the integral theorem, the antiderivative would be necessary. This is the problem, yeah?

Comment: Yes, that's right: Put a little more precisely, $\frac{1}{z}$ does not have a global antiderivative on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, and hence the proof of the C.I.F. cannot apply. On the other hand, the restriction of $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ to any simply connected domain *does* have an antiderivative: A choice of domain and antiderivative (with appropriate choice of the constant of integration) is the same thing as a choice of branch of the complex logarithm.